# Warum gibt es den Close-Button nur bei Fragen, nicht aber bei Antworten?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Unter jeder Frage gibt es diese Buttons:

```
share edit close flag
```

(und bei manchen Fragen zusätzlich auch noch `protect`)

Unter den Antworten gibt es aber nur diese Möglichkeiten:

```
share edit flag
```

(bei eigenen Antworten zusätzlich auch `delete`)

Ich wünsche mir auch für Antworten einen `close` Button, damit die Community durch Abstimmen Mehrheitlich darüber entscheiden kann, ob eine Antwort gelöscht werden soll.

Comment: [***feature requests** that cannot be realised by the moderators should be in English*](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/die-sprachvorgabe-f%c3%bcr-meta-ist-aufgehoben)

Comment: Ein close-Button für Antworten wäre ein sehr (wahrscheinlich zu) rigoroses Mittel, um unliebsame Antworten zu löschen. An sich hat "die Community" die Möglichkeit, über Downvotes dem Antwortenden sehr viel klarer und eindeutiger als durch "Close" klarzumachen, dass seine Antwort nicht besonders gut war. Da ich meine zu ahnen, auf welche Antworten sich der Wunsch bezieht, muss man der/den Fragen wahrscheinlich nur noch etwas Zeit geben "nach unten zu rutschen".

Comment: Ich kann leider die Downvotes auf die Frage nicht ganz verstehen - Sind das Meinungsäusserungen zum Thema (dann wären sie m. A. n. fehl am Platze, weil die Votes nur die Qualität der Frage betreffen sollten) oder Kommentare, weil die Frage auf deutsch gestellt wurde (was im Prinzip ja erlaubt, aber hier nicht hilfreich ist). An sich ist die Frage doch "ordentlich" in Meta?

Comment: @tofro: Dies ist Meta. Ein Upvote für einen [tag:feature-request] bedeutet „sollte umgesetzt werden“.

Comment: @chirlu Danke. Wieder was gelernt.

Answer (score 10):

Der Sinn beim Schließen einer Frage liegt darin, zu vermeiden, daß Antworten zu ihr geschrieben werden. Da es keine Antworten auf Antworten gibt, hätte ein „Schließen einer Antwort“ keine Auswirkung und wäre damit sinnlos.

Unabhängig davon können Antworten bereits gelöscht werden, und zwar mittels *delete*. Diese Funktion ist verfügbar, wenn die Antwort negativ bewertet ist. Im allgemeinen reichen drei *delete*-Stimmen aus, um eine Antwort zu löschen. Grundsätzlich soll davon aber nur begrenzt Gebrauch gemacht werden; einfach nur inhaltlich falsche Antworten sollen beispielsweise nicht gelöscht werden, sondern nur durch die Bewertung unter richtigen Antworten erscheinen.

Moderatoren können auch Antworten mit einer höheren Bewertung entfernen. Falls das erforderlich ist, etwa wegen einer Urheberrechtsverletzung, kannst du eine entsprechende Flagge setzen.

Answer (score 5):

[Closing a question](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) serves three purposes:

- **Duplicates:** redirects users quickly to answers of the same question if it was asked before.
- **On hold:** encourages improving a question to meet our requirements as defined in our Help.
- **Closed:** indicates a question that can not be answered within the scope of our Q&A site.

For closed questions no (additional) answers can be posted until the issue was resolved. All this would not apply to **answers**.

For **answers** there is a different approach by which we can say it was useful, mediorce, or poor.

> This is our [**Votes**](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

The more up-votes an answer gets the more people found it helpful. Poor answer may be down-voted to quickly indicate that this answer was misleading. In the case an answer scores -1 or less a total of 3 votes from [trusted users](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) will [eventually delete](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) it. Because deletion is quite a drastic means of moderation we need this to be restricted to moderators or high reputation trusted users. All other users should use their down votes or flags on very poor answers.

This design is inherent to the whole Stack Exchange network and it prove to work fine in the past. There is no indication that this will change in the future.

In case we want to discuss this further [Meta for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) would be the appropriate place.

Comment: Poor answers should not be deleted, they may serve as a signpost for (sometimes common) misconceptions.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン: let's hope our Trusted Users are aware of that ;)

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt einige Aufhänger, anhand derer man den Vorschlag zerreißen sollte; Chirlu und Takkat haben erschöpfend erklärt, was *schließen* eigentlich bedeutet, und was bei Antworten zur Verfügung steht.

Ein weiterer Punkt wäre die Frage nach der Mehrheit: Weder bei Schließungsstimmen noch bei Löschungsstimmen ist je eine Mehrheit, ob absolut oder relativ, nötig. Vielmehr sind beides *reine Quoren* – drei Stimmen zur Löschung (sechs von Benutzern, die keine Löschstimme haben, wenn die Frage in der Überprüfungsliste auftaucht) oder fünf Stimmen zur Schließung. Auch die Wiederöffnung (beziehungsweise Entlöschung) ist kein demokratischer Mehrheitsprozess sondern ein Quorenprozess: Die gleiche Anzahl an Stimmen genügt, um die Frage wieder zu öffnen/die Postlöschung rückgängig zu machen.

Das Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache hat 11.909 User (Stand jetzt), dementsprechend wäre eine absolute Mehrheit 5955 User, die abstimmen müssten; nur nebenbei. Eine relative Mehrheit würde eine gewisse Zeitspanne voraussetzen. Im Extremfall kann eine Frage aber trotz zwölf »Offenlassen«-Stimmen in der Überprüfungsliste geschlossen werden, wenn eben fünf User für die Schließung sind – das ist in keiner Definition eine Mehrheit, wohl aber ein Quorum.

---

Außerdem ist der Unterschied zwischen Schließung und Löschung zu beachten. Sowohl Fragen (wenn sie bereits geschlossen sind) als auch Antworten können gelöscht werden, das führt dazu, dass nur noch Benutzer mit mehr als 2000 Reputationspunkten (10000 bei graduierten Seiten) sie sehen können, bei Fragen nur, wenn sie den Link haben. Das sind nach derzeitigem Stand 79 User, wenn ich mich nicht verzählt habe. Geschlossene Fragen können hingegen von *allen* gesehen werden, also auch den anderen 11.820. Auch aus diesem Grund sollte Löschen sparsam eingesetzt werden.

---

Schließlich gilt noch die Frage, was du mit der Löschung (in deinen Worten: Schließung) einer Antwort überhaupt bezwecken möchtest. Wenn sie sachlich falsch ist, sollte man sie herunterbewerten, entsprechend kommentieren und gegebenenfalls einen Moderator bitten, eine entsprechende Notiz (*disputed* oder ähnliches) hinzuzufügen. Ist sie verletzend, sollte eine *Offensive*-Flagge gesetzt werden. Für Spam eine *Spam*-Flagge. Lalelu-Schwachsinn bekommt eine *Keine-Antwort*-Flagge. Damit sollten alle potenziellen Gründe, eine Antwort verbergen zu wollen, abgehandelt sein.

Comment: `Im Extremfall kann eine Frage aber trotz zwölf »Offenlassen«-Stimmen in der Überprüfungsliste geschlossen werden,` Nach drei "leave open" votes(iirc) geht die Frage aus der Review queue. Es braucht dann wieder ein aktives CV, damit es wieder in die Queue geht. Der Fall ist also sehr, sehr unwahrscheinlich.  Viel wahrscheinlicher ist open-close ping-pong. Da gibt es dann aber eine auto-flagge für die Mods.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Hab nie behauptet, dass es wahrscheinlich sei ;) Extremfälle sind eben meistens konstruiert.